# How to use thunk in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm learning redux,

I just want to simulate get data from the server so I use `setTimeout()` to handle it,

but it's got an error

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

although I install `redux-thunk` it does not solve it!

here's code

**./actions/userActions.js**

```
const setName = name => {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_NAME',
        payload: name,
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
};

const setAge = age => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_AGE',
    payload: age,
  };
};

export {setName, setAge};
```

**./reducers/userReducers.js**

```
const userReducer = (
  state = {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 27,
  },
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_NAME':
      state = {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload,
      };
      break;
    case 'SET_AGE':
      state = {
        ...state,
        age: action.payload,
      };
      break;
  }
  return state;
};

export default userReducer;
```

**./store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import mathReducer from '../reducers/mathReducer';
import userReducer from '../reducers/userReducer';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(
    {math: mathReducer, user: userReducer},
    // applyMiddleware(thunk) not work :]
    compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)), //same :]
  ),
);

export default store;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Main changeUsername={() => this.props.setName('Oliver')} />
        <User username={this.props.user.name} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user, //user is a key == userReducer
    math: state.math,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  // to excute the actions we want to invok
  return {
    setName: name => {
      dispatch(setName(name));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `applyMiddleware(thunk)` as combineReducers argument, it should be passed as createStore second argument.

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({math: mathReducer, user: userReducer}),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Comment: You are passing `applyMiddleware(thunk),` to `combineReducers`, it should be createStore second argument, check my updated code

Comment: OH, that's right, i want to ask you if my question is off-topic but can you explain to me what's applyMiddleware do? and why we use it?

Comment: Middleware is the suggested way to extend Redux with custom functionality. Middleware lets you wrap the store's dispatch method for fun and profit. The key feature of middleware is that it is composable. Multiple middleware can be combined together, where each middleware requires no knowledge of what comes before or after it in the chain. You can read more about here > `https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware/`

Comment: if you have time can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130935/where-can-i-dispatch-the-action-redux)